# Swing button repaint issue

Tags: java, swing, button, repaint, actionlistener

I'm  new to java and I have to get a school project done by Sunday and got a problem.

Here's the code:

```
private abstract class GamePanel {
    JPanel panel = null;
}

private class PutPanel extends GamePanel {

    JButton putShip1 = new JButton("");
    JButton putShip2 = new JButton("");
    JButton putShip3 = new JButton("");
    JButton putShip4 = new JButton("");

    ShipDirection ship1Direction = ShipDirection.NORTH;
    ShipDirection ship2Direction = ShipDirection.NORTH;
    ShipDirection ship3Direction = ShipDirection.NORTH;
    ShipDirection ship4Direction = ShipDirection.NORTH;



    JButton startButton = new JButton("Start game");

    public PutPanel(){
        this.panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(200, Torpedo.session.map.size*Field.buttonSize+300);

        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        putShip1.setSize(90, 90);
        putShip1.setLocation(55, 5);
        putShip1.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship1/full_north.png", null));

        putShip2.setSize(90, 90);
        putShip2.setLocation(55, 105);
        putShip2.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship2/full_north.png", null));

        putShip3.setSize(90, 90);
        putShip3.setLocation(55, 205);
        putShip3.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship3/full_north.png", null));

        putShip4.setSize(90, 90);
        putShip4.setLocation(55, 305);
        putShip4.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship4/full_north.png", null));

        startButton.setSize(150, 30);
        startButton.setLocation(20, Torpedo.session.map.size*Field.buttonSize+205);

        panel.add(putShip1);
        panel.add(putShip2);
        panel.add(putShip3);
        panel.add(putShip4);
        panel.add(startButton);

        startButton.addActionListener(startButton());
        startButton.addActionListener(putShip1());
        startButton.addActionListener(putShip2());
        startButton.addActionListener(putShip3());
        startButton.addActionListener(putShip4());

        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ActionListener startButton(){
        return new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 putPanel.panel.setVisible(false);
                 actionPanel.panel.setVisible(true);
             }
        };

    }

    private ActionListener putShip1(){
        return new ActionListener(){
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 selectedShip = 1;
                 putShip1.setBackground(Color.red);
                 putShip2.setBackground(null);
                 putShip3.setBackground(null);
                 putShip4.setBackground(null);
                 switch(ship1Direction){
                    case NORTH: ship1Direction = ShipDirection.EAST;
                                putShip1.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship1/full_east.png", null));
                                break;
                    case EAST:  ship1Direction = ShipDirection.SOUTH;
                                putShip1.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship1/full_south.png", null));
                                break;
                    case SOUTH: ship1Direction = ShipDirection.WEST;
                                putShip1.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship1/full_west.png", null));
                                break;
                    case WEST:  ship1Direction = ShipDirection.NORTH;
                                putShip1.setIcon(createImageIcon(Torpedo.session.map.shipPath+"/ship1/full_north.png", null));
                                break;
                 }
                 putShip1.repaint();
                 putShip2.repaint();
                 putShip3.repaint();
                 putShip4.repaint();
                 panel.repaint();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Repaint finished", "Repaint status info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); //this here hangs the program when the method is finally called
             }
        };
```

When one of the putShip* buttons is clicked, it should rotate its own icon right 90° (means changing it to the next image), but it does nothing until the startButton is clicked, which changes the panel to an other one. (Only the first button's actionListener is here, the others' are practically the same). The panel is in a JFrame with two other panels that yet do nothing.

How could I make it work properly?

Thank you.

Comment: That is because you did not add the listener to the other buttons besides startButton

Comment: Ohshit :D
It must be really late then...
Thanks :P

Comment: @Chuk Lee you should put that as answer so that it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As told by user Chuk Lee add the `ActionListener`s to the `putShip*` buttons too. Heres a little bit of code for you to add:

```
    startButton.addActionListener(startButton());
    startButton.addActionListener(putShip1());
    startButton.addActionListener(putShip2());
    startButton.addActionListener(putShip3());
    startButton.addActionListener(putShip4());

    putShip1.addActionListener(putShip1());
    putShip2.addActionListener(putShip2());
    putShip3.addActionListener(putShip3());
    putShip3.addActionListener(putShip3());

    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setVisible(true);
```